# Multiply single character by given number in String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have one goal:

1) Multiply character in String n-times (character, String, n [int] - from user input)
Example:

> User input1 (String) : future
>   User input2 (char) : u
>   User input3 (int) : 2
>   **Output**: fuutuure

First i tried with char[] array but IndexOutOfBoundsException brought me back to reality. Second try-StringBuilder but its not working aswell-empty result window. Should I use StringBuilder (and if answer is yes-how?) ? Or there is other, better solution.
Thank you for help.

```
package Basics.Strings;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Ex4 {

static String giveAWord() {
    Scanner scanWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give a word");
    String word = scanWord.nextLine();
    return word;
}

static char giveALetter() {
    Scanner scanALetter = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give a letter");
    char let = scanALetter.next().charAt(0);
    return let;
}

static int giveANumber() {
    Scanner scanNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give a number");
    int numb = scanNumber.nextInt();
    return numb;
}

static String multiplyLetter(String word, char letter, int number) {

    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
      if (sb.charAt(i)==letter) {
    sb.append(i*number);
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = giveAWord();
    char letter = giveALetter();
    int number = giveANumber();
    System.out.println(multiplyLetter(word, letter, number));
}
}
```

Comment: I've not really used much the `StringBuilder` class, but I'd say you should use the `insert()` method instead of `append()` so you can specify the position where you want to insert your character

Comment: Refer to method [`insert(int,char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-char-) in class `java.lang.StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in your `multiplyLetter` method that would make it not work.

**First**, you have to initialise the `StringBuilder` using the word so:

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word) ;`

Else, your `StringBuilder` will be empty.

**Second**, you should use the `insert(int pos, char c)` method, so you can specify where you want tthe character inserted.

And **last**, you can't just multiply a `char` and an `int` and get away with it. If you want to repeatedly insert a character, I think you should use a loop.

So, in summary, try:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(word);

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
  if (sb.charAt(i)==letter) {
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < number ; j++ ) {
        sb.insert(i, letter);
        i++ ;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice I added `i++` inside the loop, as `sb.length()` will increase with each character inserted.

Also, maybe someone more experienced can provide with a more efficient way than just using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using at least Java 11 (eleven) then the following will work:

```
String word = "future";
String letter = "u";
int count = 2;
String replacement = letter.repeat(count);
String result = word.replace(letter, replacement);
```

Note that only method `repeat(int)` was added in Java 11.
Method `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` was added in Java 5

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 functional way:

```
String alterString(String input, Character charMatch, int times) {
  return input.chars()
           .mapToObj(c -> (Character) c)      // converting int to char
           .flatMap(c -> {
             if (c == charMatch) {
               Character[] ca = new Character[times];
               Arrays.fill(ca, c);
               return Arrays.stream(ca); // stream of char c repeated 'times' times
             }
             return Stream.of(c);
           })
           .collect(
             // following is the string collecting using StringBuilder form stream of characters
             Collector.of(
               StringBuilder::new,
               StringBuilder::append,
               StringBuilder::append,
               StringBuilder::toString,
             );
           );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is by using the following functions:

1. [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)
2. [Collections#nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T))
3. [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

### Demo:

```
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the string: ");
            String str = kb.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the character: ");
            String ch = kb.nextLine();
            System.out.print("How many times to repeat?: ");
            int n = kb.nextInt();

            String result = str.replace(ch, String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, ch)));
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        }
    }
```

**A sample run:**

```
    Enter the string: future
    Enter the character: u
    How many times to repeat?: 2
    Result: fuutuure
```